# Laravel: When unregistered users visit the website for the first time - show the dialog where they can confirm that they are 18+

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I need to create the following: when an unregistered user visits the website for the first time - show the dialog to confirm that he or she is 18+. I am not sure what would be the best way to implement something like that, I have started with defining a new `AgeMiddleware`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Sentinel::guest()) {
        $age_confirmed = $request->cookie('age');
        if (!$age_confirmed) {
            return redirect('home')
                ->with('age_popup', 'You need to confirm that you are 18+'); // infinite redirecting !!!
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

So, my idea was to store a cookie named `age`. If there isn't that cookie - redirect to the home page and show the confirmation dialog box. To show that dialog, I am "flashing" `age_popup` session data: `->with('age_popup', 'You need to confirm that you are 18+')`. Finally, in my Blade **layout** file I would add bootstrap modal code which would be the confirmation dialog box, and which would appear only if there is `$age_popup`, something like:

```
@if ($age_popup)
   <script>
       $('#ageModal').modal('show')
   </script>
@endif
```

When that modal is shown - when a user confirms that he is 18+ (when he or she clicks on the "OK" button) - it will be closed and (somehow) a new cookie called `age` will be stored.

But there are two problems with all this:

**1.** As you can see in the `AgeMiddleware` - if there isn't that cookie - a user will be redirected to the home page. This will never work because it will keep redirecting to the home page **infinitely**, and it will probably end up with some error.

So the question is - where and how can I check this cookie (which will determine whether or not to display a modal (popup)? Ideally, without any redirecting.

**2.** When that modal is shown - when a users confirms that he is 18+ (when he clicks on the "OK" button) - how can I create that `age` cookie without doing a standard (non-Ajax) request, without any page reloading... just close the modal and set the cookie?

Comment: Leave out the `AgeMiddleware` from the `home` route. That way you won't have infinite redirect. You can listen for the close event on the modal `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { ...` to set the cookie. You can use [jQuery cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the middleware. Then in your blade, replace code with:

```
@if (\Sentinel::guest() && request()->cookie('age'))
   <script>
       $('#ageModal').modal('show')
   </script>
@endif
```

Then, once the user inputs his age and presses ok/close, set the cookie as follows in the modal close event handler/callback:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie("age", age, 365);
```

Comment: Instead of `@if (\Sentinel::guest() && request()->cookie('age'))` I used `@unless (\Sentinel::guest() || isset($_COOKIE['age']))` and then everything works fine. Anyway, I'll check your answer, THANKS!